# I am using keras and I get an error message saying "No module named 'lstm'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to set up Keras with the following code:

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
import lstm, time #helper libraries
```

Unfortunately it gives me two error message and I can't get my head around it:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:205: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6
  return f(*args, **kwds)
```

and

```
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lstm'
```

Thanks in advance,
Victor

Comment: Your error is unrelated to Keras but refers to your helper libraries.

Comment: as by the comment above just remove ```lstm``` in the last line of the snippet. For the ```RuntimeWarning``` you might wanna have a look here: https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build

Comment: Thanks a lot! It removes the error message but brings it back as soon as I type the next line: `X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = lstm.load_data('sp500.csv', 50, True)`

Comment: what library should lstm be?

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the following two:

```
pip install seq2seq-lstm
```

or

```
pip install phased-lstm-keras
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, the following solved the issue:

```
from keras.layers import LSTM
```